# I can't assign value to a generic variable with same type

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I have created a generic class with 2 type parameters but I can't assign a value to the List **principalList** that have the same type. _D_Data.GetGrupoProductoList() returns a **List<E_grupo_producto>**

```
public class N_TablaSolaBase<TPrincipalInfo, TData>
    where TPrincipalInfo : E_grupo_producto, new()
    where TData : D_Producto, new()
{
    private TPrincipalInfo principalInfo= new TPrincipalInfo();
    private List<TPrincipalInfo> principalList = new List<TPrincipalInfo>();
    private TData _D_Data = new();

    public List<TPrincipalInfo> GetPrincipalList()
    {
        var lista = _D_Data.GetGrupoProductoList();

        MessageBox.Show((lista.GetType() == principalList.GetType()).ToString());
        // show true
        principalList = lista 
        // Can't convert List<E_grupo_producto> to List<TPrincipalInfo>
        return principalList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) problem.

If you have; `class Animal`, `class Dog : Animal` & `class Cat : Animal`. Then a `List<Animal>` can store and retrieve any animal. But if the caller is expecting a `List<Dog>`, then you can't give them a `List<Animal>` as there might be a `Cat` in it. But also, if the caller has asked for a `List<Animal>`, you can't give them a `List<Dog>` as the caller might try to put a `Cat` in it.

Your `class N_TablaSolaBase<TPrincipalInfo>` allows the caller to specify if they want a `List<E_grupo_producto>` or only a `List<OtherProduct>` for some `class OtherProduct : E_grupo_producto`. If they've asked for only `List<OtherProduct>`, you can't give them a `List<E_grupo_producto>`.

You could add a runtime cast to return the list if the types actually match. But then why have the generic parameter if the only supported value is `E_grupo_producto`?

```cs
var lista = _D_Data.GetGrupoProductoList() as List<TPrincipalInfo>
    ?? throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Or you could change your `D_Producto` class to add a generic parameter, to ensure that `GetGrupoProductoList` returns a `List<TPrincipalInfo>`.

```cs
public class N_TablaSolaBase<TPrincipalInfo, TData>
    where TPrincipalInfo : E_grupo_producto, new()
    where TData : D_Producto<TPrincipalInfo>, new() {...}

public class D_Producto<TPrincipalInfo>
    where TPrincipalInfo : E_grupo_producto, new() {
    public List<TPrincipalInfo> GetGrupoProductoList() {...}
}
```

Comment: var lista = _D_Data.GetGrupoProductoList() as List<TPrincipalInfo> // This part works for me.